# Unable to logon locally to Server 2012 R2 after removing Exchange from SBS2003

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, windows-sbs-2003

I receive the following error when logging on locally to a newly introduced Windows Server 2012 R2 Standard.

```
The sign-in method you are using isn't allowed. For more info, contact your network administrator.
```

Everything in the migration was going well. I ran adprep on the SBS2003. Joined the server to the domain. Installed AD services and promoted the 2012R2 box as a DC. Everything was still going well. I began to decommission the SBS2003 box by removing Exchange. Now I'm unable to login locally to the 2012R2 box as the domain administrator. I can still login locally as the administrator of the SBS box. Any help is appreciated...

Comment: Update - after the SBS2003 server restarted it's not allowing local logins either. RDP login works, however.

Comment: I was able to edit the Domain Controller Security Policy locally on the 2003 SBS server. Now I'm able to login locally to the 2003 server, still unable to login to 2012 DC.

Comment: Well after fighting and fighting I was able to enable remote logins to the 2012 DC, edit the local policy, and login locally. What I've found is the SYSVOL and netlogon shares are missing from the 2012 DC, so GPOs are not replicating properly... now I have to figure out how to rebuild those.